# How to style codeigniter multi level menu?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I want to create a multi level menu with codeIgniter.

My table structure is this:

> id -- category -- parent_id

I use this code in my model:

```
function all_category_ordered($level = 0, $prefix = '<li>') {
    $rows = $this->db
        ->select('id,category,parent_id')
        ->where('parent_id', $level)
        ->order_by('id','asc')
        ->get('category')
        ->result();

    $category = null;

    if (count($rows) > 0) {

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $category .= $prefix . $row->category . "\n";
            // Append subcategories
            $category .= "</li>".$this->all_category_ordered($row->id, $prefix . '*') ;
        }
    }
    return $category;
}
```

it works fine and the out put of the code is like this:

```
<li>menu 1</li>
<li>menu 2</li>
<li>menu 3</li>
<li>*submenu 1</li>
<li>menu 4</li>
<li>*submenu 2</li>
```

but I want to change the model to out put in `ul` and `li` correct order to style it correctly.

preferred order:

```
<ul>
<li>menu 1</li>
<li>menu 2</li>
<li>menu 3
<ul>
<li>*submenu 1</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>menu 3
<ul>
<li>*submenu 1</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this php code and changed to CodeIgniter MVC

```
<?php
function has_children($rows, $id) {
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if ($row['parent_id'] == $id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function build_menu($rows, $parent = 0) {
    $result = "<ul>";
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if ($row['parent_id'] == $parent) {
            $result .= "<li>{$row['category']}";
            if (has_children($rows, $row['id'])) {
                $result .= build_menu($rows, $row['id']);
            }
            $result .= "</li>";
        }
    }
    $result .= "</ul>";
    return $result;
}
$category = array(
        array('id' => 1, 'parent_id' => 0, 'category' => 'category 1'),
        array('id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 0, 'category' => 'category 2'),
        array('id' => 3,  'parent_id' => 1, 'category' => 'sub category'),
        array('id' => 4,  'parent_id' => 2, 'category' => 'sub category'),
        array('id' => 5,  'parent_id' => 1, 'category' => 'sub category'),
        array('id' => 6,  'parent_id' => 5, 'category' => 'sub category'),
);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>menu</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo build_menu($category, 0);?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using recursive function - **that's good**. You should stick with this approach, but you don't control when particular `ul` should be opened and closed and that's what missing.

Below you will find my very, **very old** crap that should give you a hint about controlling the process of opening / closing the list on every level.

```
<?php

$query = mysql_query('SELECT menu.id, menu.id_parent, menu.link, menu.alt, library.title FROM library library, menu menu WHERE menu.link = library.id ORDER BY menu.level ASC');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

    $menu_array[] = array('id'=>$row['id'], 'id_parent'=>$row['id_parent'], 'link'=>$row['link'], 'alt'=>$row['alt'], 'title'=>$row['title']);
}

function menu($id) 
{   
    global $menu_array;

    $has_childs = false;
    $result = array();

    // nothing if empty
    if (empty($menu_array))
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach ($menu_array as $value)
    {
        if ($value['id_parent'] == $id)
        {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }

    foreach ($result as $value)
    {
        if ($has_childs === false)
        {
            $has_childs = true;

            if ($value['id_parent'] == 0)
            {
                echo ('<ul id="root">'); // root level
            }
            else
            {
                echo ('<ul>'); // sub levels
            }
        }

        echo ('<li><a href="#">'.$value['title'].'</a>');

        menu($value['id']);

        echo ('</li>');
    }

    if ($has_childs === true)
    {
        echo ('</ul>');
    }
}

menu(0);
```

Again, adjust it. Remove query and replace it with what your CI model returns. See if the structure is similar. This is your to give you example function `menu()`.

EDIT:

Here's DB structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_parent` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `link` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `alt` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=74 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;

--
-- Zrzut danych tabeli `menu`
--

INSERT INTO `menu` (`id`, `id_parent`, `link`, `level`, `alt`) VALUES
(66, 0, 197, 3, 'Strona główna'),
(3, 2, 199, 1, 'Kanał RSS'),
(4, 2, 200, 2, 'Archiwum newsów'),
(5, 0, 24, 6, 'Depeche Mode'),
(6, 5, 1, 1, 'Biografia grupy'),
(7, 10, 26, 1, 'Biografia'),
(8, 15, 94, 1, 'Biografia'),
(9, 19, 107, 1, 'Biografia'),
(10, 5, 25, 2, ''),
(11, 10, 27, 2, 'Albumy'),
(12, 10, 29, 3, 'Single'),
(13, 10, 30, 4, 'Video'),
(14, 10, 31, 5, 'Teksty'),
(15, 5, 93, 3, ''),
(16, 15, 95, 2, 'Albumy'),
(17, 15, 102, 3, 'Single'),
(18, 15, 103, 4, 'Teksty'),
(19, 5, 104, 4, ''),
(20, 19, 108, 2, 'Wytwórnia płytowa Toast Hawaii'),
(21, 19, 109, 3, 'Tost Hawajski'),
(22, 5, 105, 5, ''),
(23, 22, 111, 1, 'Biografia'),
(24, 22, 110, 2, 'Odejście z Depeche Mode'),
(26, 22, 221, 3, 'Albumy'),
(27, 22, 219, 4, 'Single'),
(28, 22, 220, 5, 'Teksty'),
(29, 5, 106, 6, ''),
(30, 29, 112, 1, 'Biografia'),
(31, 29, 113, 2, ''),
(32, 0, 55, 7, 'Dyskografia'),
(33, 32, 164, 1, 'Albumy'),
(34, 32, 165, 2, 'Single'),
(35, 32, 166, 3, 'Video'),
(36, 0, 17, 8, 'Teksty utworów'),
(37, 0, 53, 9, 'Trasy koncertowe'),
(38, 37, 76, 1, ''),
(39, 37, 77, 2, ''),
(40, 37, 78, 3, ''),
(41, 37, 79, 4, ''),
(42, 37, 80, 5, ''),
(43, 37, 81, 6, ''),
(44, 37, 82, 7, ''),
(45, 37, 83, 8, ''),
(46, 37, 84, 9, ''),
(47, 37, 85, 10, ''),
(48, 37, 86, 11, ''),
(49, 37, 87, 12, ''),
(50, 37, 88, 13, ''),
(51, 37, 89, 14, ''),
(52, 37, 90, 15, ''),
(53, 37, 91, 16, ''),
(54, 0, 201, 10, 'Ciekawostki'),
(55, 0, 202, 11, 'Fani'),
(56, 0, 203, 12, 'Forum'),
(57, 0, 42, 13, ''),
(58, 0, 196, 14, ''),
(59, 0, 41, 15, ''),
(60, 59, 204, 1, 'Kontakt'),
(61, 59, 277, 2, ''),
(62, 37, 282, 17, ''),
(63, 62, 280, 1, ''),
(67, 0, 198, 5, 'Aktualności'),
(68, 67, 199, 1, 'Kanał RSS'),
(69, 67, 200, 2, 'Archiwum newsów'),
(70, 62, 289, 2, ''),
(71, 55, 292, 1, ''),
(72, 56, 293, 1, '');
```

Sure, feel free to use it. :) As I said. It's very old code but it's fully working. You can see exactly pasted example [here](http://depechemode.cc). Id and Id_parent - these two hold relation between each other, change link to your href just something that you will put inside `href`, level is depth and alt is the title of your menu entry. So you have some stuff to clean but it will work in 100%. Create a controller in CI, move query part to new method inside your model and there you go. Once your list will be generated you can style it in your view. :)

Comment: thanks slick for your answer. can i your your code in codeigniter MVC? i haven't check it.

Comment: would you give the database structure that you use in this code??

Comment: Hi, I edited my comment. Clean it a little bit and you should be fine. It will work in 100%. :)

Comment: Sure. Please, let us know what were your final results. :)

Comment: thanks for your kindly assistant @stick. the problem solved

Comment: That's great. :) Please mark my post as the one that solved your problem.